# Precision and recall are the same within a model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall

I am working on a multiclassification project and I noticed that no matter what classifier I run the precision and recall are the same within a model.

The classification problem has three distinct classes. The volume of the data is rather on the small side with 13k instances divided into test (0.8) and train (0.2).

Training data has a shape of (10608, 28) and labels are the shape of (10608, 3) (binarized label).

The classification is imbalanced:

- label 0 represents 30% of all labels
- label 1 represents 4% of all labels
- label 2 represents 66% of all labels.

I am comparing different classifiers, to later focus on the most promising ones. While calculating precision and recall for each model I noticed that they are always the same within a model.

Due to how precision and recall are calculated they can be the same when the number of false-negative predictions equals the number of false-positive predictions  `FP = FN`.

[image]

Examples:

## SGD classifier

```
sgd_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(random_state=42))
sgd_clf.fit(data_tr, labels_tr)
y_pred_sgd = cross_val_predict(sgd_clf, data_tr, labels_tr, cv=5) 
cm_sgd = confusion_matrix(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_sgd.argmax(axis=1))  

cm_sgd:
array([[1038,   19, 2084],
       [ 204,   22,  249],
       [ 931,   48, 6013]], dtype=int64)
precision_score(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_sgd.argmax(axis=1), average="micro")  
0.666760935143288
recall_score(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_sgd.argmax(axis=1), average="micro") 
0.666760935143288

FP=FN=3535
```

## Logistic regression

```
lr_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(random_state=42, max_iter=4000))
lr_clf.fit(data_tr, labels_tr)
y_pred_lr = cross_val_predict(lr_clf, data_tr, labels_tr, cv=5)
cm_lr = confusion_matrix(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_lr.argmax(axis=1))

cm_lr: 
array([[ 982,    1, 2158],
       [ 194,    7,  274],
       [ 774,    9, 6209]], dtype=int64)

precision_score(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_lr.argmax(axis=1), average="micro") 
0.6785444947209653
recall_score(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_lr.argmax(axis=1), average="micro") 
0.6785444947209653


FP=FN=3410
```

## Random forest

```
rf_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
rf_clf.fit(data_tr, labels_tr)
y_pred_forest = cross_val_predict(rf_clf, data_tr, labels_tr, cv=5)
cm_forest = confusion_matrix(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_forest.argmax(axis=1)) 

cm_forest: 
array([[1576,   56, 1509],
      [ 237,   45,  193],
      [1282,   61, 5649]], dtype=int64)
precision_score(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_forest.argmax(axis=1), average="micro")
0.6853318250377074
recall_score(labels_tr.argmax(axis=1), y_pred_forest.argmax(axis=1), average="micro")  
0.6853318250377074

FP=FN=3338
```

How likely is it that all the models have the same recall and precision within a model? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because you are calculating the `micro` average of your scores. In the docs, it is described as:

> Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.

Now here is the catch: in classification tasks where every test case is guaranteed to be assigned to exactly one class, computing a `micro` average is equivalent to computing the accuracy score. This is why you get the same result for precision and recall in each model: you are basically computing the accuracy in all cases.

You can verify this by using [`accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html?highlight=accuracy#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score) and comparing the results.

As a consequence, you should better evaluate the precision and recall of your models with either `macro` or `weighted` average instead.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for solving my confusion. I read that the micro average is better than macro for imbalanced classification. That is also why I selected it. I believe that the weighted average would be more useful in my case than the macro average since it is weighted by support. I have one more question if I may: what metric would in my case (i.e. imbalanced multiclass classification) be the best to compare different models? While reading a lot about it there seems to be no clear go-to metric.

Comment: The "best" choice (if such a thing exists) really depends on the underlying problem and what you are willing to tolerate more, false positives (FP) or false negatives (FN). Let's say you are less concerned about producing FN predictions and want to minimize FP predictions, you would probably focus more on achieving high precision scores (compare with the formula). For the opposite case, you would focus more on recall respectively. If you cannot afford such a trade-off between these two, the F1-score is a good measure because it is the harmonic mean of precision and recall.

Comment: That being said, this is just merely a guidance rather than an extensive answer. There are even more metrics like [F-beta score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html#sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score) and the area under the [precision-recall curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve) which might also be suitable in your specific case. But I think this should be a good start for you to dig deeper into this topic and hope it will help you further.

Comment: Can we prove that in a multi-class labeling task, the micro-average of precision is in fact the accuracy. i.e. the proportion of correct answers?  If precision for class i is Pr(i) and the number of items in the hypothesized class is size(i), then Pr_micro = (Sum_i Pr(i) * size(i)) / total with Pr(i) = TP(i) / (TP(i) + FP(i)) therefore Pr_micro = (Sum_i TP(i)) / total = accuracy, because TP(i)+FP(i) = size(i).  Interestingly, for this to work, the micro-averaging must be done using sizes of hypothesized classes rather than reference ones.