# GridSearch CV multiple metrics result in same score values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv

I'm tuning my models with GridSearchCV. There are multiple scoring metrics used - precision, recall and accuracy. However, when I inspect the `cv_results_`, all 3 metrics give the same score values.

Here is my code.

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)

param_grid = {
    'max_depth': range(5, 11, 1),
    'max_features': range(10, 21, 1),
    'n_estimators': [10, 100],
    'min_samples_leaf':[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
}

scorers = {
    'precision_score': make_scorer(precision_score, average='micro'),
    'recall_score': make_scorer(recall_score, average='micro'),
    'accuracy_score': make_scorer(accuracy_score)
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid = param_grid, 
                           scoring=scorers, refit='precision_score', return_train_score=True,
                          cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 3)

grid_search.fit(X,y)
```

The scores returned by `cv_results`:

`pd.DataFrame(grid_search.cv_results_)[['mean_test_precision_score', 'mean_test_recall_score', 'mean_test_accuracy_score']].head(10)`
[image]

The way I made my `X` and `y` (if that matters):

```
X = data_merge.drop('label', axis=1)
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(data_merge['label'])
```

I'm running Scikit Learn 0.24.2 and Python 3.8.10

Comment: Wow, I've never seen this happen. Either there is really something spectacular about your data and model combination where precision, recall and accuracy actually come out to be the same (nearly impossible) or something in the way you are viewing the data? Could you also include the call to `cv_results`?

Comment: @SamarthBhatia I didn't find anything spectacular about my data. I have tested it with different combinations of parameters in `GridSearchCV`, all yield the same results. The table I attached is the sample output from `cv_results`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792001/precision-and-recall-are-the-same-within-a-model This explains it pretty well!

Comment: @SamarthBhatia Thank you! You saved my day! Indeed setting `average` to `weighted` instead of `micro` gave me different precision and recall output.

Comment: you might also want to look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html#sklearn-metrics-precision-score), there are more options for `average`

Comment: Another helpful answer in this context might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469371/interpreting-auc-accuracy-and-f1-score-on-the-unbalanced-dataset/62471736#62471736) where I try to explain when to choose which averaging strategy. If you find this one and the answer provided above by @SamarthBhatia helpful, consider upvoting them. I see this issue coming up rather often, and it might make it easier for others to find this information.

Comment: Thanks @afsharov. This is a very clear explanation of the different average strategies. I hope others could be benefited from it too.